# Can I define therefore using a syllogism?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is this a complete definition of therefore: $((a \rightarrow b) \land a):\iff(\therefore b)$

for an algebraic example, would this definition allow me to say:
$x+1=2 \therefore x=2-1 \therefore x=1$

If not, what is a complete definition of therefore?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot have a double arrow there. If you did, from *any* $b$ you could conclude $a.$

Comment: I think there is a problem: the LHS has $a$ has a variable with no quantifier while the RHS does not. "Therefore" means consequence, so it is intrinsically a binary operator. What is the problem with $\implies$?

Comment: At least, the LHS should have a quantifier "$\exists a$".

Comment: @Taladris I see, so does $((a\rightarrow b)\land a) : \therefore b$ make a proper definition?

Comment: @UnfunnyVirgin: is $:$ supposed to mean definition? There is still a problem with $a$ on the LHS.

Comment: @Taladris does b not need a quantifier?

Comment: @Taladris also, yes i mean definition by :

Comment: @UnFunnyVirgin: you don't need any quantifier for $b$. You would write something like "Let $b$ be a proposition. We define $\therefore b$ by $(a\rightarrow b)\wedge a$". Then we know exactly what $b$ is, but not what $a$ is supposed to be in such a proposition, From your example, and as Lapin suggested, you probably want to define $\therefore b$ as $(\exists a); (a\rightarrow b)\wedge a$.  Also, as I already mentioned, "therefore" means consequence, so it seems odd to me to want to define it as a unary operator.

Comment: No, b can be true and the LHS false.

Comment: Maybe it could mean the same as [$\models$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say " therefore" you commit yourself to 2 things :

(1) to the factual truth of the premisses

(2) to the logical implication relation between the premisses and the conclusion.

But those two things cannot be done in the language of propositional logic.

This question deals with the distinction between language ( also called " object language")  and meta-language.

In the propositional logic language, one writes down expressions, formulas.

In metalanguage, one can judge the formulas, saying, for example : " this formula is valid" ( for example : $\models P\lor \neg P$)  or " this formula is a logical consequence of these premisses " ( without committing oneself to the truth of the premisses or of the conclusion), for example
$\{P, P \rightarrow Q \} \models Q$ .

I would say that " therefore" is still one level above, because it implies that one commits oneself to the truth of the premisses.